# Difference between a greedy and a non-greedy dataflow block with boundedcapacity defined

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I have a `BatchBlock` with `BoundedCapacity` defined on it

```
var _batchBlock = new BatchBlock<int>(2, new GroupingDataflowBlockOptions
                                      {BoundedCapacity = 100 });
```

So if the queue capacity reaches a 100 the block postpones every message received until a spot becomes available.
In this case is the batch queue considered greedy or non-greedy ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The block is greedy, but not because of how it handles the items above 100, but the ones below 2. You can set the greedy value to `false` (`true` is the default) and then the block would only actually consume items when there are enough to send a batch, until then they are postponed:

```
var batchBlock = new BatchBlock<int>(2, new GroupingDataflowBlockOptions
{
    Greedy = false,
    BoundedCapacity = 100.
});
```

> The BatchBlock class operates in either greedy or non-greedy mode. In greedy mode, which is the default, a BatchBlock object accepts every message that it is offered and propagates out an array after it receives the specified count of elements. In non-greedy mode, a BatchBlock object postpones all incoming messages until enough sources have offered messages to the block to form a batch

From [Dataflow (Task Parallel Library)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx)