"BatchBlock" does not work properly in non-greedy mode
When I use greedy mode, everything works as expected. But when I enable non-greedy mode, аt the moment of executing "foo.Receive()", the thread hangs while waiting.
BatchBlock<int> foo = new(1, new()
{
    //Greedy = false
});

foo.Post(1);

Console.WriteLine(foo.Receive());

What am I doing wrong?
.NET version: 8.0.303,
Windows 11

While the answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/26394644/982149 seems to explain the behavior, I couldn't fix it : https://dotnetfiddle.net/GQ2jnN

Fildor, Hello, I reviewed this question earlier. That post only explained the difference between greedy and non-greedy modes, but my question is different: "Why does this error occur when using non-greedy mode?"

Since I want able to fix it, I couldn't find an answer to that, neither. Sorry.

Fildor, I found a solution, but I had to use "BufferBlock". Thank you.

In case it helps someone in the future (I had to additionally use "BufferBlock")
BufferBlock<int> buffer = new();
buffer.Post(1);

BatchBlock<int> foo = new(1, new()
{
    Greedy = false
});

buffer.LinkTo(foo);

Console.WriteLine(foo.Receive());


Doesn't that defeat the purpose of a non- greedy batch block? This way, you basically built a greedy batchblock. Just less reliable.

Fildor, Initially, I needed to add data to the "BatchBlock" in non-greedy mode. However, the thread hung while waiting (this behavior did not occur in greedy mode). You are right, greediness is present here, as in this example, there is a direct call to "foo.Receive()", which was done to simplify understanding of my problem. To make the call non-greedy, instead of directly calling "foo.Receive()", one can use "ActionBlock", as shown here: "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-use-joinblock-to-read-data-from-multiple-sources".

Fildor, by the way, I fixed the main issue by removing the "foo.Complete()" call, which was placed before "foo.Receive()". However, I still find it strange that the example doesn't work without the additional use of "BufferBlock".

Fildor, After I wrote you the previous response, I realized why the example with "BufferBlock" works in non-greedy mode. I'm not entirely sure, but I believe that the number "1" cannot be divided among multiple consumers, such as "BatchBlock"; this entity is intended for only one consumer. However, if the number "1" is written to the "BufferBlock" source, it means that this number can be processed by one of several consumers, not just one. And this means that it becomes possible to process the "1" non-greedily by these consumers.

Hmm. Maybe. Tbh: a little too much "magic" for my taste. I think I would experiment with RxNet or something "hone brewed" to avoid unpleasant surprises.

@Fildor Rx has it's own set of quirks, especially if it's used for anything other than its intended purpose, which is working with streams of events. Trying to built a dataflow with Rx is unlikely to be pleasant or successful.

I guess so. That's why I would probably just code it myself. @TheodorZoulias
